# How to remove duplicate values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove duplicate values from an array.

Here is my array

```
$arr=array([0]=>123,[1]=>223,[2]=>323,[3]=>123,[4]=>223);
```

For removing duplicate values, I used `array_unique()` function, but it still shows the same array.

Is there any method to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably used `array_unique()` but did not assign its result to an array variable. Look at how @diEcho is assigning the result to `$result`.

Comment: Now the question is... did you assing the array_unique to a variable ? `i.e $result = array_unique($arr);`

Answer (score 2):

use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
<?php
$arr=array([0]=>123,[1]=>223,[2]=>323,[3]=>123,[4]=>223);
$result = array_unique($arr);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: @ oscar sorry it was mistake , i was suppose to post that in other,thanx for pointing it,

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me.

```
$arr = array(0 => 123, 1 => 223, 2 => 323, 3 => 123, 4 => 223);

var_dump(array_unique($arr));
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(123)
  [1]=>
  int(223)
  [2]=>
  int(323)
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/y2D24Gog).

Note that `array_unique()` returns a new array, it doesn't take the array by reference, so you'll need to assign the returned array somewhere.

Comment: array_merge() and array_filter(), here am used to merge number of array and remove null values of array, after that i had used array_unique() to avoid duplicate values,but it gives the same array

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$arrUnique = array_unique($arr);
print_r($arrUnique);
```