# How to remove duplicate keys in array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array called `$myarray` -

```
id position status name

4    23        4   john

3    45        3   mike

4    23        0   john

7    25        2   sam
```

etc.

i need to filter array by "id" and when similar records found i need to evaluate by "status"key to remove number that's 0 or less than "status" in matching row. Is there some way to do it fast like some function?

Comment: I'm confused about your array structure. If I wanted mike's name, would I look at $myarray[1]['name'] (row #1) or $myarray[3]['name'] (id=3)

Comment: Note: There are no duplicate keys in PHP arrays. Only duplicate values. Just as this question is a duplicate of many others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960190/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes all occurences of `status=0`. If u want to keep these rows, when there is no other matching `id`, remove the `$value['status'] > 0 &&`

```
$cleanarray = array();
foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    if (
        $value['status'] > 0 && (
            !array_key_exists($value['id'], $cleanarray) ||
            $value['status'] > $cleanarray[$value['id']]['status']
        )
    ) $new_cleanarray[$value['id']] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_multisort(..)`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to sort by `id` ASC then `status` DESC. Then you could walk through the sorted array and delete rows where the `id` has been seen before.

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

This might be of your use

Comment: `array_filter` doesn't compare two elements in an array.. It only looks at one.

Comment: The callback function is only passed one element of the array.