# Remove duplicate keys from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting strange behavior of array. I am getting an array with duplicate keys. I checked that this is due to the Datatype of the keys. How can i make it unique. This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [1811258] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => true
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 2501
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2400
            [subgroupid] => bux_364905
            [desc] => GE Refrigerator - Side by Side GC5SHEXNQ..
            [id] => 1811258
        )

    [1812193] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => true
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 293
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2410
            [subgroupid] => 0
            [desc] => STAINLESS STEEL DOUBLE BOWL - 20 GAUGE
            [id] => 1812193
        )

    [1811258] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 2501
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2400
            [subgroupid] => bux_364905
            [desc] => GE Refrigerator - Side by Side GC5SHEXNQ..
            [id] => 1811258
        )

    [1852936] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 525
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2489
            [subgroupid] => 0
            [desc] => 
            [id] => 1852936
        )

    [1812193] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 293
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2410
            [subgroupid] => 0
            [desc] => STAINLESS STEEL DOUBLE BOWL - 20 GAUGE
            [id] => 1812193
        )

)
```

I have tried `array_key_exists()` function to check:

```
$saved=(array)json_decode($reviewdata->options);
 foreach($optioncodes as $key=>$optioncode){
        $option=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * from {$prefix}builder_phaseplanoption where OptionCode='{$optioncode}' and SubdivisioNID='{$subdivision}'");
        if($option){
            if(array_key_exists($option->ID,$saved))
                $saved[$option->ID]=(object)array('status'=>true,'count'=>1,'price'=>$option->UnitPrice,'attributes'=>'','groupid'=>$option->OptionGroupID,'subgroupid'=>$option->Sub_OptionGroupID,'desc'=>$option->OptionLongDesc,'id'=>$option->ID);
        }
    }
```

But no effect.I also tried to change the data type.Like this

```
$optid=(string)$option->ID; // now this shoud string but no effect
                    $saved[$optid]=(object)array('status'=>true,'count'=>1,'price'=>$option->UnitPrice,'attributes'=>'','groupid'=>$option->OptionGroupID,'subgroupid'=>$option->Sub_OptionGroupID,'desc'=>$option->OptionLongDesc,'id'=>$option->ID);
```

I know this is due to the problem that keys in the saved array are strings while the new keys are numbers. How can i convert them to the same type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will remove the keys.No?

Comment: Sorry in last comment it's a `array_unique()` try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate keys in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550826/how-to-remove-duplicate-keys-in-array)

Comment: *"I am getting an array with duplicate keys."* -- there are two possibilities: either you have found a serious bug in PHP, which is practically impossible, or there is a problem in your code.

Comment: Sorry i think it was you actual array

Comment: @axiac I have mentioned in my question that "I know this is due to the problem that keys in the saved array are strings while the new keys are numbers. How can i convert them to the same type"

Comment: @NiravJoshi [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) removes the duplicate **values** from an array. There is no function to remove the duplicate keys because there is no way to have duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: @axiac its possible if data type is not save.int 123 and string 123 can be saved as keys in array. This is my case

Comment: @MKD It is still not possible to have duplicate keys using different types. The string keys that contain only digits and are valid base-10 numbers are automatically converted to numbers by PHP when it puts them in the array. Check this: https://3v4l.org/6l776

Comment: then why these are duplicates? You can check my printed array.

Comment: @axiac if your comment is true then how it works when i change the datatype? Check my answer.

Comment: Post the value of `$reviewdata->options`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147397/discussion-between-axiac-and-mkd).

Comment: Its a json object {"1811258":{"status":"true","count":"1","price":"2501","attributes":"","groupid":"2400","subgroupid":"bux_364905","desc":"GE Refrigerator - Side by Side GC5SHEXNQ..","id":"1811258"},"1812193":{"status":"true","count":"1","price":"293","attributes":"","groupid":"2410","subgroupid":"0","desc":"STAINLESS STEEL DOUBLE BOWL - 20 GAUGE","id":"1812193"}}

Comment: Please  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php link, I think it will be help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this but i am not sure if it is the correct way to do this. If there is any better way then please give your suggestions.
I changed the data type and create a new array.And it remove the duplicate values.

```
$newsaved=array();
foreach($saved as $key=>$value){
    $stroptid=(string)$key;
    $newsaved[$stroptid]=$value;
}
```

Now this is the output

```
Array
(
    [1811258] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 2501
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2400
            [subgroupid] => bux_364905
            [desc] => GE Refrigerator - Side by Side GC5SHEXNQ..
            [id] => 1811258
        )

    [1812193] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 293
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2410
            [subgroupid] => 0
            [desc] => STAINLESS STEEL DOUBLE BOWL - 20 GAUGE
            [id] => 1812193
        )

    [1852936] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [count] => 1
            [price] => 525
            [attributes] => 
            [groupid] => 2489
            [subgroupid] => 0
            [desc] => 
            [id] => 1852936
        )

)
```

Comment: The JSON you posted in the question's comments contains invisible characters and it's invalid. I wonder how you managed to decode it. `json_decode()` refuses to decode it for me: https://3v4l.org/cg5WC